# scan table for checked and textboxes not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

what are some other ways to write the following. i have a table of 3 rows. Each row has a column with 3 checkboxes and another column with just a textbox.

What I want to happen is when the values are loaded from the database, if a row has any of its checkboxes checked or its textbox is not equal to blank highlight that row.

```
<table border="1" id="distributionTable">
<tr>
<td>Full Run</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[0].IsHome" /> H
<input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[0].IsRack" /> R
<input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[0].IsRunOut" /> O</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Collection[0].Quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>City Zones</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[1].IsHome" /> H
<input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[1].IsRack" checked="checked" /> R
<input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[1].IsRunOut" /> O</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Collection[1].Quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>12345</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[2].IsHome" /> H
<input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[2].IsRack" /> R
<input type="checkbox" class="deliveryAction" name="Collection[2].IsRunOut" /> O</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Collection[2].Quantity" class="quantity" value="1000" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

here's the jquery i wrote:

```
$('#distributionTable tr').each(function(){ 
    $this = $(this);

    var hascheck = false;
    $this.find('.deliveryAction').each(function(){
        if (this.checked){
            hascheck = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (hascheck)
    {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }


    if ($this.find('.quantity').val() != ''){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'orange'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (assuming that there is one text input per row):

```
$('#distributionTable tr').filter(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
    if($this.find(':checked').length != 0)
        return true;
    if($.trim($this.find(':text').val()) != '')
        return true;
    return false;
}).addClass('hi');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XXBWP/

Comment: very nice, appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the HTML is generated at the server, which already knows which checkboxes are checked or inputs have a value, so just add a class to the row that highlights it.